# Ask + Parenthetical remark (with or without “to”?)

Tags: grammaticality

Be the next line of dialogue:

*‘Edward, how can this be possible?’ Vicky asked, not so much (*to*) Edward but (*to*) herself, and then left.*

Is this sentence grammatically correct with or without “to”?

I’d be very grateful to anyone helping me to settle this question.

Comment: It isn't very good, with or without any _to_'s. The fact that there is a doubt about the grammar draws attention to the construction instead of the message. Instead of performing prepositions, try _Vicky asked, addressing not so much Edward as herself_.

Comment: @JohnLawler isn't it incorrect to "ask a question to X"? I can't figure out what rule it breaks since I can "give a flower to X" and "pay attention to X", but the first formulation feels actually "wrong" to me, though I can't figure out why it would be if it is. Also I can "pose a question to X" which is practically identical! - what gives??

Comment: I'd move the "so much": Vicky asked, not Edward **so much as** herself. Are you sure you have a parenthetical remark? The second comma is the separator for the second clause "and left."

Comment: Using offsetting brackets rather than commas seems to add padding that shrouds the unusual grammar.  << asked (not so much Edward as herself) >>.

Comment: Or, ... you could just use _said_ instead of _asked_. There's a question mark there already, and _say_ doesn't cause these difficulties. Don't worry about being "correct" at the expense of clarity and momentum.

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations! They will be useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "to" necessary here. The sentence is grammatically correct without the "to"s

Note, also, that you never `ask` a question "to" someone. You ask a question `of` someone.

So - if you wanted to modify your sentence it would also be correct if it was framed as
`Vicky asked not so much of Edward but of herself`.